# Использование полей в коде финализатора

Tags: c#, .net, clr

В книге *Рихтер Дж., CLR via C#. Программирование на платформе Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 на языке C#. 4-е изд.* на странице 577 есть обзац:

> Методы Finalize вызываются при завершении уборки мусора для объектов,
>   которые уборщик мусора определил для уничтожения. Это означает, что
>   память таких объектов не может быть освобождена немедленно, потому что
>   метод Finalize может выполнить код с обращением к полю. Так как
>   финализируемый объект должен пережить уборку мусора, он переводится в
>   другое поколение, вследствие чего такой объект живет намного дольше,
>   чем следует. Ситуация не идеальна в отношении использования памяти,
>   поэтому финализации следует по возможности избегать. Проблема
>   усугубляется тем, что при преобразовании поколения финализируемых
>   объектов все объекты, на которые они ссылаются в своих полях, тоже
>   преобразуются, потому что они должны продолжать свое существование.
>   Итак, старайтесь по возможности обойтись без создания финализируемых
>   объектов с полями ссылочного типа.

И я не могу из этого понять следующее:

1. *... потому что метод Finalize может выполнить код с обращением к **полю**.* Тут имелось ввиду если это поле **ссылочного** типа?
2. или если речь идет о том, что объект нельзя удалить, так как его поле(я) используется финализатором, то что дает перевод такого объекта в следующее поколение, ведь в следующем поколении будет ровно такая же картина - он там тоже будет использовать поле в своем коде?

Comment: `или если речь идет о том, что объект нельзя удалить, так как его поле(я) используется финализатором, то что дает перевод такого объекта в следующее поколение, ведь в следующем поколении будет ровно такая же картина - он там тоже будет использовать поле в своем коде?` - вызовется финализатор -> объект боьше не нужен -> удаляем его из памяти

Comment: `... потому что метод Finalize может выполнить код с обращением к полю. Тут имелось ввиду если это поле ссылочного типа?` думаю, тут имелись ввиду поля объекта, у которого есть финализатор. Не важно, ссылочные они или значимые - они тоде занимают память. Ссылочные занимают память ссылкой на кучу, значимые - значением.

Comment: Если вы думаете об освобождении управляемых ресурсов в финализаторе, то этого делать не надо. [Because the order in which the garbage collector destroys managed objects during finalization is not defined, calling this Dispose overload with a value of false prevents the finalizer from trying to release managed resources that may have already been reclaimed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)

Comment: @tym32167, _вызовется финализатор -> объект боьше не нужен -> удаляем его из памяти_ то есть, сборщик мусора каким-то образом определяет, что объект попал в поколение 1 или 2 из-за того что обращался к полям и сразу вызывает у него финализатор не проверяя есть ли ссылки на него?

Comment: допустим, сборщик мусора увидел объект в пераом поколении, на который нет никаких ссылок. Что он делает - он проверит, есть ли у этого объекта финализатор. Если нет - то просто удалит его из памяти. Если есть, то удалять его нельзя, надо поставить его в очередь финализации и перевести во второе поколение. Когда очередь финализации дойдет до этого объекта, тогда будет вызван финализатор, только после этого объект можно из памяти удалять.

Comment: каким именно образом тот или иной объект попал в первое или какое либо другое поколение сборщику мусора абсолютно фиолетово. Он работает с текущим состоянием объекта.

Comment: будет ли объект в финализаторе обращаться к полям или не будет - сборщику обсолютно не интересно. Ему интересен только факт наличия финализатора.

Comment: Я нашёл этот абзац в оригинальном издании. Перевод выполнен весьма точно, практически дословно.

Comment: Как тут уже сказано, пока объект дожидается финализации, он удерживает в своих полях как значимые типы, так и ссылочные. И эти ссылочные типы тоже не могут быть удалены сборщиком мусора.

Comment: @tym32167 в этом всё равно нет логики, что мешает сборщику мусора вызвать финализатор пока объект в первом поколении?

Comment: @Zergatul чтобы вызвать финализатор объекта, надо поставить этот объект в очередь финализации. Чтобы поставить объект в очередь, надо быть уверенным, что объект можно удалить из памяти. Чтобы быть уверенным, надо выполнить поиск по графу ссылок. Поиск по графу ссылок- часть сборки мусора. То есть к моменту вызова финализатора, объект уже пережил какую то сборку мусора. Пережить сборку мусора = покинуть первое поколение (поколение номер 0).

Comment: @tym32167 теперь понятно :) добавляйте ответ. Как я понял, вся фишка в том, что есть 2 процессинга в GC: один останавливает все потоки, ищет объекты которые можно удалить, и очищает память. Этот процессинг не может запускать финализаторы, так как какой-то умник может прописать в финализаторе Thread.Sleep и всё зависнет. Поэтому существует другой процессинг с очередью объектов для вызова финализатора Этот процессинг работает в отдельном потоке паралельно с работой основной программы. Кстати, при завершении программы финализаторы магическим образом срабатывают на объектах в первом поколении.

Comment: @Zergatul сорри, я должен был это отметить - про два процессинга. Там, если мне память не изменяет, даже отдельный поток для финализации запущен. То есть сбока мусора и финализация в разных потоках по идее работают. Но это не точно, года 3-4 уже не обновлял свои знания )

Comment: @tym32167 отдельный поток точно запускается еще при старте программы, в нем финализаторы запускаются. На счет того, где запускается сборка мусора - не знаю

Comment: @Zergatul это скорее всего [зависит от режима](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals), в котором он запущен.